# Thymeleaf: th:selected when comparing Long to Long

Tags: thymeleaf

I have read several posts on this but none of the answers seem to apply.

1. My command object has a field Long businessId.
2. My command object has a hashmap <Long, String> of businesses (id and businessname)

My form (relevant part thereof) is as follows

```html
<tr>

   <td><label for="businessId" th:text="#{label.business}">Business
    Message: </label></td>
   <td><select name="businessId">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option th:each="entry : ${userAdminForm.businessMap.entrySet()}"
     th:value="${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value}" th:selected="${entry.key} eq ${userAdminForm.businessId}">
     Dropdown value</option>         
   </select>
   
  <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('businessId')}"
    th:errors="${userAdminForm.businessId}">Error Message</p> 
     </td>
   </tr>
```

the th:selected compares entry.key which is Long with businessId which is Long. I assume no converter is needed. I am not using th:field so I assume th:selected is appropriate here.

However, it does not work.  Advice would be most welcome

Answer (score 2):

I use `th:selected` with `eq` expressions like this:

```
th:selected="${entry.key eq userAdminForm.businessId}"
```

and it works, so it should work for you too, I guess. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks a million. but alas, no, it doesn't work. Any guesses as to what else I could be doing wrong?

Comment: This DOES work. My error was in webflow scoping and when I fixed that the answer provided here worked